# Add column of row numbers for each group of successively increasing dates

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have DataFrame which has column with Date and other columns with some values and, let's say, first 100 rows are in order according to the date, and from 101 till 200 again the same Dates, only different values, and so on. I would like to add a column which count rows from 1 to 100, and start again from 1 when the date repeat.
Example

```
Date       | Value | RowNum
2000-01-01 |   2   |    1  
2000-02-01 |   10  |    2
.
.
.
2003-12-01 |  11   |    100
2000-01-01 |  32   |    1  
2000-02-01 |  14   |    2
.
.
.
2003-12-01 |  4    |    100
```

I need this to pivot this table where columns are dates, values are values and RowNum will be index.
Thank You for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the *exact* same dates repeat, your problem becomes a very simple `cumsum` and `cumcount` problem:

```
m = df.Date.eq(df.at[df.index[0], 'Date']).cumsum()
df['RowNum'] = df.groupby(m).cumcount() + 1
```

---

If not, you can check the `diff`:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], errors='coerce')
m = df['Date'].diff().dt.total_seconds().fillna(-1).lt(0).cumsum()
df['RowNum'] = df.groupby(m).cumcount() + 1
```

Or, similarly, by converting the underlying NumPy array to float and then diffing:

```
s = pd.Series(df['Date'].values.astype(float), index=df.index)
df['RowNum'] = df.groupby(s.fillna(-1).lt(0).cumsum()).cumcount() + 1
```

Comment: My bad, I simplified my example, and unfortuantely not always new data will start with exactly the same date, maybe be same small difference, but I think it leads me to an idea now how to do this

Comment: `TypeError: cannot astype a datetimelike from [datetime64[ns]] to [int32]`

Comment: @goskan Hmm, perhaps there is a time component too. Try `.astype(float)` instead? (see edit please)

Comment: @goskan Idea, try timedelta diffing, edited once again

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation**

Create a new column and iterate through the data frame and simply use %100 of the index column. This will work just fine if you exactly have 100 same dates as you mentioned above.

**Code**

```
df[RowNum] = 1
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    RowNum_val = i%100
    df.set_value(i,'RowNum',RowNum_val)
```

**Resources**

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-set_value/
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_pandas/python_pandas_iteration.htm